# How to remove completely the Panel border in delphi?

Tags: image, delphi, delphi-2010, border, tpanel

In my application, i've created a signup form and i need to show an Error Icon whenever an Edit is empty or contain some error. But the image haven't a Name property and therefor i am unable to to call the Hide the image by its name. Therefore i decided to put an image into the panel and hide the panel instead. something like :

```
    if(lenght(edit1.text)=0) then
       Panel1.show else Panel1.hide;  // this code shows or hide the image
```

The problem is that the panel's border still appear after setting BorderStyle to bsNone.

How to hide completely the panel's border ?

Comment: How do you display the image? If it is a TImage that is placed on the form then it will have a name. If you create it from code then just keep a reference to it.

Comment: What's preventing you from simply *giving* the image component a name? It's *your* program, so if there's something about it that makes your task difficult, you can fix it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Your actual problem most likely can be solved without adding a `TPanel`, but I still answer your actual question here.)

Set `BevelInner` and `BevelOuter` to `bvNone`.

By the way, your code can be written more elegantly as

```
Panel1.Visible := Length(Edit1.Text) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I set following properties which worked for me in situation like you have

```
BevelInner := bvNone;
BevelOuter := bvNone;
BevelKind := bkNone;
```